# Fetch api and wait state to update in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

**I have an array object. I want to iterate through the array and dispatch action. Unfortunately without waiting for the first object finish dispatching, 2nd object starts dispatching action and so does the 3rd, 4th, 5th.. objects.**

I'm currently doing a updateCategory function for user to upload image and then update the category. User may drag and drop many images and give the images different tags. I keep the images and tags in an array object. My concept is like this, from the array object, upload image and then immediately update the category with the uploaded image and its tag, one by one.

Here's the problem. I fetch upload image api and update category api from iterating the array, using Promise. While not waiting for the redux state to be updated, the it immediately fetch upload image api. And lastly, the updated category is always the last image and the last tag in the array.

This is my code:

```
function uploadAndUpdateSubcategoryMedias(Image, ArticleCategoryId, ArticleSubcategoryTag) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return dispatch(uploadSubcategoryMedia(Image)).then(() => {
            const uploadedImg = getState().media.media.Data;
            var MediaFiles = [];
            MediaFiles.push(uploadedImg);
            return dispatch(updateArticleSubcategoryMedias(ArticleCategoryId, ArticleSubcategoryTag, MediaFiles))
        })
    }
}

function subcatMediaTesting(subcategoryMediasArr) {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        var promises = [];
        subcategoryMediasArr.forEach((item) => {
            var response = dispatch(uploadAndUpdateSubcategoryMedias(item.image, item.articleCategoryId, item.tagName));
            promises.push(response);
        })
        return Promise.all(await promises)
    }
}
```

How can I iterate the array object so that it dispatch `upload_Media_Request` -> `upload_Media_Success` -> `update_Category_Request` -> `update_Category_Success` then the next item start this process again? Or maybe there is another way to complete this so I can update all the categories but not only the category of the last item?

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that dispatch() returns a promise.  You do that in your fetch call: dispatch(...).then(...).  I would try dispatch(FIRST_ACTION).then(...put your fetch call here...).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yea I actually used dispatch(...).then(...) and I referred this from https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1676#issuecomment-215413478 async action creator. If I have only one image to be uploaded it did follow the pattern like UPLOAD_MEDIA_REQEUST -> UPLOAD_MEDIA_SUCCESS -> UPDATE_ARTICLE_CATEGORY_MEDIA_REQUEST -> UPDATE_ARTICLE_CATEGORY_MEDIA_SUCCESS. But why when I want to call in an array it will not wait for it to return the promise and straight away dispatch the first action?

Comment: When you fire the array via the map method, you’ve effective created a bunch of independent promises, each promise is those 4 dispatches.   The problem is that each promise from the array is independent of any of the others.  You want to create a promise chain from the array.  So item maps to promise and next item maps to promise linked to previous item’s primise.  (I don’t have my computer with me, otherwise I’d produce a code snippet).  I hope that makes sense and helps!

Comment: Ahh I got it! All those running independently. No wonder. But how can I create the promise chain from the array?

Comment: I would pass the array to the thunk you've got.  If you can send the array into a single fetch, that would solve your problem.  If you cannot, then you can promise chain out the fetch calls inside the thunk.  Now the complex functionality is in one place, and not spread out between your React comp and your thunk.  You could use the await operator to create an array of promises (aka fetch calls), and then run Promise.all(...), put the data together and then update state.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?  If so, can you post an answer?

Comment: Hi, thank you for catching up! Too bad I haven’t figured out how to solve it. Btw I tried the method Promise.all but the array still fetch api independently. Am I do wrong on the above edited code?

Comment: Hey @westandy, I solved my problem already. I changed another method to do it without using array.map or forEach. Thanks for your help! Appreciate!